# SMARTY - How to display smarty errors instead of 404.tpl?

Tags: php, smarty

I need troubleshoot problem on my site based on SMARTY template. PHP display errors is enabled. Smarty if there is error display 404.tpl without error message. What should I change or add and where ? I think i use smarty 2.5.+ .Thank you very much. Excuse my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's really Smarty related.  You should check if you have set custom error handler using `set_error_handler` in PHP. It's very possible in PHP in case of warnings or errors you have rule that simple displays 404.tpl file and logs errors for example to file.